# Sonar Issue-HttpClient instances should always have socket and connect timeouts

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1

```
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
```

For this piece of code Sonar is throwing **HttpClient instances should always have socket and connect timeouts**

```
    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().useSystemProperties().build();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(apiEndPoint);
```

For this piece of code as well sonar is stating **HttpClient instances should always have socket and connect timeouts**

Need help in understanding the resolution and why is this happening